# includepdf - centering/scaling problem when pages in pdf are not of the same size(dimension)

Tags: margins, pdfpages, scaling, includegraphics

I have lots of pdfs to `\includepdf` and each has 3 to 4 pages with **different dimensions** (height and width might be different for each page.

I have used

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,UTF8,scheme=plain,twoside,draft]{ctexart}
%\ctexset{today=old}

%% SOME KEY packages used
\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate,amsfonts}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % uses graphicx
\usepackage[top=1.8cm,bottom=1.8cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\includepdf[
pages={-},
pagecommand={},
width =0.95\textwidth, 
height=0.95\textheight,
keepaspectratio
]{filename}
```

hoping that for each pdf and each page included, it would automatically, rescale and center to `fit` into the pages, using either `0.95\textwidth` or `0.95\textheight`. But the output is not ....

I used `draft` option as a test.

Some pages look like it has even scaled into the margins..

How could I change, so that every page in the included pdf are scaled to `fit` and center in the page?

Thanks.

[image]

This one go into the right margin...
[image]

only centered vertically???
[image]

**not** centered vertically or horizontally!!!!

Is it using a scaling factor from it's first page for the whole included pdf??

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default pdfpages only checks the size of the first page of an include pdf (at least I think it still does it). And this means that fit options are related to the size of this page. But you can loop over the single pages instead:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fitallincludepdf[2][]{%
  \AM@findfile{#2}%
  \setkeys{pdfpages}{#1}%
  \expandafter\AM@readlist\expandafter{\AM@pagestemp}%
  \@for\xxx:=\AM@pagelist\do{%
    \edef\AM@tmp{[\unexpanded{#1},pages=\xxx]}%
    \expandafter\includepdf\AM@tmp{#2}%
  }}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\includepdf[fitpaper,pages=-]{diffsize}
\fitallincludepdf[fitpaper,pages=-]{diffsize}
\end{document}
```

The normal includepdf gives then this:

[image]

And the other this

[image]

The diffsize pdf was created with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[fitpaper]{example-image-A}
\includepdf[fitpaper]{example-image-10x16}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry about any confusion here. `fitpaper` would completely ignore any headers and footers, even if I add `pagecommand={}` back. If there a way to loop `width=0.95\textwidth, 
height=0.95\textheight,
keepaspectratio` for each page? This is the problem here as we identified...Hence I have more control over the `scaling` for each page.

Comment: After a bit playing around, I think adding them in the definition of `\fitallincludepdf` solved it! Possible to make it as options for `\fitallincludepdf` ?