# How to prevent from using a page template when using pdfpages package?

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages

When using the `\includepdf`, the package uses a page (by default the 1st page) as a page template for other pages. But if `\includepdf[pages=1-,fitpaper=true]{write}` is used then, only the 1st page of the pdf is fitted while the other pages are fitted to the size of the first page.
*write.pdf* has different sized pages and I need to keep it that way only in the new pdf that I'll be creating.
So how can we disable the page template functionality or at least use it in such a way that each new page is used as a template for that page?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539337/2388

Comment: Thank you, was able to solve the problem using loops as mentioned (though I used different kind of loops using ```pgffor``` package)